# is Secondary chord (triad, seventh) can overlapping Fifth when is not substitute chord?

Tags: chord-progressions

[image]

i giving the situation. image is a resolution of V34

left case of the image is

'D-F' in V going to 'E-E' in I as contrary motion.
and from that position, a 'harmonic connection' (any notes shared between two chords should remain in the same voice, and the rest of the voices move the shortest distance possible while avoiding breaking any other rules.) with the ii6's F-D is possible.

but right case of the image is

can't harmonic connection if 'D-F' in V going to 'E-E' in I as contrary motion. so F is going to up.

However, my curiosity here is that if V's 'D-F' goes to the I's 'E-E as contrary motion , can the following progress be made.

**E-G-E-C -> D-A-F-A**

I think that progression is can be harmonic connection. but as far as I know Secondary chord is can't overlapping Fifth.
because 5 in the secondary chord is 3 in the primary chord.

but if is not substitute chord?
can overlapping Fifth and Is it possible to proceed as above?

Comment: I'm having a difficult time understanding your question. Are you able to notate the progression you're asking about and post the image?

Comment: @aaron i don't have image just an example I made by transforming the on the right side of the image in the main text.

D-G-F-B(V) -> E-G-E-C(I) -> D-A-F-A(ii)

Comment: I see. So you're wondering if the progression in your comment breaks any rules of harmony or voice leading?

Comment: @aaron yeah, for Exactly, is that situation, can overlapping Fifth if is not substitute chord? that's my question.

Comment: @aaron I thought you were going to answer my questions soon.

Comment: @aaron But there's something I'm missing: D-A makes a perfect fifth. It's probably not going to work because of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Chord progression: V7-I-ii]

The chord progression described, V7-I-ii, contains two problematic aspects:

- It is the exception to double the third of a major chord — the I chord in this case. Since the third is not functioning as a leading tone, no rules are broken. However, the doubling is avoided, because it gives a hollow sound to the chord, as it does in this instance.
- There is a hidden fifth moving from I to ii between the soprano and bass parts. This is more problematic that the doubled third, especially since it occurs between outer voices.

Comment: "Since the third is not functioning as a leading tone, no rules are broken." You mean leading tone in V? And what do you mean ' not functioning as a leading tone' i don't understand.

Comment: And im talking about perfect 5 in ii is a sop and bass.

Comment: @guss2222 Regarding the leading tone: I am speaking of the I chord. The E is doubled, which is unusual, but E is not the leading tone, so it's okay. If the following chord were F major instead of D minor, then E would be a leading tone.

Comment: i understand. and what about another question?

Comment: @guss2222 I updated my post.

Comment: i'm confused about this, I know that if a perfect 5 comes out of a similar motion (same direction, different intervals), it's called concealed progression and is prohibition.

Comment: Hidden consecutives <-- It seems to use this expression in English.

Comment: @guss2222 There are no hidden fifths in your harmonization. Your harmonization is fine; it does not break any rules.

Comment: listen, sop A in ii is 'skip down' from C in I . and bass D in ii is 'step down' from E in I. and that's a similar motion. Here's an explanation. 1c. Hidden Consecutives Also known as “concealed” or “exposed” consecutives, these are a little harder to spot, but must be avoided. Hidden consecutives happen when: The bass and soprano parts form a perfect 5th or octave AND The 5th/8ve is approached by similar motion AND The soprano part is approached by a leap (not by step).

Comment: @guss2222 If you already have your answer, why are you asking me?

Comment: I don't know why you think that way. I'm just wondering if you can explain something I don't know. But i think maybe you just missed this. no offence

Comment: To be precise, you made me ask a question. you says 'There are no hidden fifths '. So I'm just asked again to see if the information I know is incorrect. If you said that hidden fifth was right I'd just skip it.

Comment: @guss2222 You are correct. There is a hidden fifth between the soprano and bass.

Comment: ok. Somehow the question seems to have been resolved. sorry to bother you.